# Mysql Query: find all the posts along with x ascending which has nggallery id in post_content column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a table wp_posts with a column **post_content**. some of the post entry has **[nggallery id=x]** inside post_content column. I want to find all the posts along with x (gallery id no, it is different for different gallery) ascending which has **nggallery id** in post_content column. How can I do it?

Comment: You should always post your table schema when posting SQL questions on here (and preferable some example data AND the queries you've tried so far that didn't work).

Comment: It is very hard to under stand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%[nggallery id=%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just don't ask :)

```
select
left(substring(post_content,locate('[nggallery id=',post_content)+14,5),locate(']',substring(post_content,locate('[nggallery id=',post_content)+14,5))-1)  as NumValue, post_content
from wp_posts
WHERE post_content LIKE "[nggallery id=%]"
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he meant this:

SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE "[nggallery id=%]"

MySQL String Comparison Functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html